# popup displaying bottom left corner instead of mouse location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have this code that used to work fine with a normal event listener but I just changed to html onclick() for the trigger and now my popup always displays at the bottom left; I don't understand why this is different:

HTML:

`<span onclick="edit(this)"></span>`

JS:

```
function edit(target){
  var left = (target.clientX - 40) + "px";
  var top = (target.clientY - 40)+ "px";
  $("#popup").css('left',left);
  $("#popup").css('top',top);
  $("#popup").css('position','fixed');
  $("#popup").fadeIn(500);
}
```

CSS

```
 #popup{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 500;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px black solid;
 }
```

Comment: This `<span> onclick="edit(this)"</span>` is all kinds of invalid

Comment: what do you mean ? It triggers fine and I get the target fine before; only the screen location seem not to update correctly

Comment: Does your <span> with the click event have a pos of absolute? The popup is probably binding to the document body or some other relative element in your document.

Comment: Its invalid markup. It works cause the browser corrects it for you.

Comment: @theGrizz I have update the question with CSS; only fixed position when displayed

Comment: @Ravenous you probably mean the html typo ? I corrected the question

Comment: This link may help https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: Check my answer. Your code is okay, you are just checking the same span with the same coordinates every time, you need a parent element that covers more than just that and check for MouseEvent coordinates on that.

Comment: Just move onclick to body and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need events for this, coordinates are part of MouseEvent, you can't obtain them via (this), you can however pass the event object via (event).

Comment: I have been trying your answer but no success yet; I tried to change the `span` to `div` and `body.clientX`. Is this what you mean ? I also tried `MouseEvent.screenX` from your link

Comment: Or `span onclick="edit(event)"`, sorry, I really thought you wanted a pop-up to appear near mouse cursor every time, on any click on page.

Comment: Sweet !!! Thank you so much ! I need this to get attribute also so I ended up using both `onclick="edit(this, event)"` and it worked just fine

Comment: Yeah, sorry, misunderstood use case at first.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, yesterday I was searching how to capture mouse position and found this piece of gold

```
function managePosition(event){
  var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

  event = event || window.event;

  if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
    eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
    doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
    body = eventDoc.body;

    event.pageX = event.clientX +
                 (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
                 (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
    event.pageY = event.clientY +
                 (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
                 (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
  }

  //here you can use event.pageX to set your element.style.left and
  //event.pageY to your top. For example: (g = documentGetElementById(id))
  g('bubble').style.left = (event.pageX + 30) + "px";
  g('bubble').style.top = (event.pageY - 200) + "px"
}
```